# Nginx subfolder response inconsistent

Tags: nginx

I have a front-end application (in reactjs) and a static blog that I want to display from the same server through nginx. My application is accessible at the root of the domain / and my blog is currently accessible on a subdomain blog.domain.com. But I'm currently switching from a subdomain to the /blog subfolder on the same domain and I have an issue while displaying the blog from the subfolder. The problem only appears on chrome and is quite inconsistent. What happens is that when browsing /blog I get a 404 from the js application, not the static site (the css styles are different so it's easy to spot who responded). If I refresh the page without cache (ctrl + shift + R) I get a response from static blog. If I click on a link, again I get a 404 from the js page and if I clean-refresh now I get the correct page from the blog. Any f5 on a page redirect to a 404 from the js page.

In firefox or private navigation, everything seems fine though so I was thinking about a common cache issue in the browser at first but the fact that after dropping the cache I still get 404s from the wrong directory makes me think about some parameters that would be sent and not treated the same way in one case or another.

I have noticed that ctrl-shift-R redirects me to /blog/ from /blog when the blog is displayed properly but an f5 on /blog/ still gives a 404 from the js frontend. It might mean that the 301 to the trailing slash does something more. But a ctrl-shift-R on /blog/ does not trigger a 301 (just a 200) with the expected website displayed.

Here is my nginx config file for this site:

```
server {
  listen 443 http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 http2 default_server;
  root /opt/react_folder/build;
  index index.html;
  server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  location /blog {
      alias /opt/blog_subfolder;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

 ... backend block

 ... ssl block
}

server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
  rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: You can run nginX in debug mode with `error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug` - and you will see exactly why you get 404 errors - but keep in mind that DEBUG mode will quickly generate large log file - so switch this mode on only for a few minutes, while you perform the requests. Then you can quietly inspect the log file for as along as you wish.

Comment: it doesn't help much because this is not a proper error on the side of nginx. It's actually hard to fathom, for a live example of what's happening here is the domain in question https://eu-remoters.com/blog/

Comment: Yes, it should not reply with 404 - but since it does, the reason for this behavior will be evident in the debug log. Perhaps one location block is taking precedence over another but you do not suspect this, or something else is happening. The debug log will tell you exactly what nginX is doing.